# document.getElementById('id').innerHtml = Static Resource Image

Tags: visualforce, javascript, static-resources

I have written one JS function on click of radio button,

I want to show my Static Resource - Image file

Help me out here

```
**document.getElementById('id').innerHtml = ****************** My Static Resource Image ************
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In JavaScript Function:**

```
document.getElementById("oImg").src='{!URLFOR($Resource.YOUR_RESOURCE_NAME)}';
```

---

**VF CODE**

```
<div id="imgid">
    <img src="" id="oImg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<apex:form>
<apex:inputCheckbox  onclick="showImage()"  />
<script>
function showImage()
{
    document.getElementById('shw').innerHTML = '<img src="{!Resource.ImageName}" />';
}
</script>
<div id="shw"> </div>
</apex:form>
```

Comment: I guess this will break image, In some cases it does work, but above answers always works well.